# Hardware/BIOS Monitoring Tools with Email or other Reporting Functionality

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, hardware, reporting

I am looking for recommendations for good software that can report the status of hardware it is installed on through an email or IP Connection.

A bit of background, my organization has 160 locations across the state that host a server at each location. These locations do not have any consistent network connections or a steady connection to a data collection or reporting server, they do however have access to the internet and so can report over email or other indirect reporting tool.

I am looking for some kind of software that can monitor the hardware status, particularly the health of the mirrored raid arrays on the server and report back when that hardware shows danger levels or the raid array becomes unhealthy. We currently use Windows Server 2003 enterprise in our environment.

We currently use IBM System x3200 and System x3200 M2 servers in our environment. We have looked at IBM's web page, but we have not found any good monitoring software that meets our needs.

Any recommendations for software that could handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Found, also by IBM, specifically the company that made the RAID array in our model of servers.

Comment: Glad to hear!  Any details? (raid vendor, is it a service that runs, etc).

Comment: It is a program offered by the RAID vendor, LSI, called MegaRAID Storage Manager. It creates a monitoring service, then allows you to manage all physical and logical drives on the machine. It has error logs that can attach to windows system logs, and you can customize the errors to set severity and action when they occur, including sending an email off to any email you choose and any SMTP server you choose. The email includes the error, as well as the name of the server generating the error. http://www-947.ibm.com/systems/support/supportsite.wss/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5077712&brandind=5000008

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this capability is included with the servers.  You probably just need to install and configure the agents on each server, and setup a management console on one workstation

IBM Systems Director 6.1 Technical Paper

ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/common/ssi/sa/wh/n/xbw03006usen/XBW03006USEN.PDF

"Simpliﬁed interface to trigger events automatically, such as e-mail notiﬁcation or task execution. " (page 9).

Comment: Looking into it now. :) If it tests out well, I'll take this as my solution.

Comment: It appears that the System Director Software will not serve my needs. The system director collects information from other machines using an agent, then shoots off reports. We do not have a consistent connection to our equipment that would allow the use of this software. I need something that monitors the RAID array directly on the server, then independently sends off an email notification if it fails.